# How to hide/show ui grid rows based on search condition

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

So I have been struggling with a problem involving a ui-grid that I have implemented. We have a complicated search for a table where a user can search for IDs for employees and they can also search IDs for companies. There are textboxes corresponding to employee/company ID so the user knows where to start typing. Right now, I am conditionally swapping the column visibility based on where the user begins typing (employee ID hides company columns as an example). However, I need a way to also hide the company/employee rows because the columns are showing empty values and are displaying when the user has nothing in the search box.

Research: I am toggling the columns based on an answer I found where I am just changing column visibility, but it seems there is no row visibility option. However, the only row hiding functionality seems to be checking against a static value and in this case it needs to be dynamic.

I am considering just using two different grids and toggling visibility based on the search boxes typed in, but I was trying to see if I could use just one grid.

Any help would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: I think you could use standard filter option in gridOptions columnDefs. This allows for dynamic filtering as well as static filtering. Take a look at [the tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20103%20Filtering).
If this does not solve your problem, or I did not understand, maybe you could include some screenshots as to what you mean, or maybe even a plunkr showing what you've got so far.

Comment: Please include what you have done like images for what you have done and what you are expecting as a final output

Comment: Hey thanks for the responses and I did look at the filtering. I thought about changing that, but I didn't want to dive into that just for 2 columns out of the entire grid. I can show screenshots, but really the problem doesn't really need screenshots to display the problem. Essentially, I have two sets of data with different columns that need to be filtered into one grid. I think @Remko was correct in the filtering is probably my best option. I went with 2 grids though since I needed it pretty quickly, was dropped last minute on me.